# Selection Sort has a few elements out of place

Tags: c++

I am trying to use Selection Sort without pointers or addresses. However, the output of this selection sort sometimes has a few elements out of place.

I've tried using cout to see the index of i and minIdx right before the swap, and the indexes are right. However, it doesn't seem to swap them to the right places.

```
void SortArray (int v[], int size) {

    int i, j, minIdx, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            int minIdx = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                    if (v[j] < v[minIdx]) {
                        minIdx = j;
                    } 
                    temp = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[minIdx];
                    v[minIdx] = temp;
            }

            PrintArray(v, size);
            cout<<" "<<endl;
    }

}
```

This is the final sort. 64 and 62 are wrong.

0
24
34
41
58
64
62
67
69
78

Comment: There must be some common site out there with a botched selection sort. This is the second one in less than a week with the swap included inside the j-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing too many swaps.  The swap should happen after the inner loop completes, e.g.

```
for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) 
{
    if (v[j] < v[minIdx]) 
    {
        minIdx = j;
    }
} 
temp = v[i];
v[i] = v[minIdx];
v[minIdx] = temp;
```